# Deleting document in PyMongo from id

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I seem to be struggling to find the right way of deleting a document. I.e. should I be using remove() or delete_one() for example and also what is the canonical method of deleting by id, which is a `string`.

I.e. should I be using the following:

```
mongo.db.xxx.delete_one({'_id': { "$oid" : str(_id) } })
```

or can I use another format?

```
mongo.db.xxx.remove({'_id': { "$oid" : str(_id) } })
mongo.db.xxx.remove({'_id': ObjectId(_id) })
```

What is the canonical form?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

`remove` is deprecated in the 3.x release of pymongo, so the current canonical form would be to use [`delete_one`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html?highlight=delete_one#pymongo.collection.Collection.delete_one):

```py
from bson.objectid import ObjectId

result = mongo.db.xxx.delete_one({'_id': ObjectId(_id)})
```

The call returns a [`DeleteResult`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/results.html#pymongo.results.DeleteResult) in which you can inspect the `deleted_count` field to see if it found a document to delete

Comment: Thanks, do you know the error exceptions? I cannot get debug at the moment. I.e. if the ID isn't found.

Comment: When I try this at the command line, I get the following: `NameError: name 'ObjectId' is not defined`

Comment: @Navonod You need to import that if you're not already doing that. See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do:

```
result = mongo.db.xxx.delete_one({})
```